# Connect to guest solaris 11 from host windows 7 using virtual box

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, solaris

I have installed virtual box in windows 7 and Installed solaris 11 as virtual machine. I have changed network settings to host-only adapter but I cant do ping from my host computer to virtual machine or vice versa. My ip address for virtualbox doing ipconfig is 192.168.56.1 and the ip address of my solaris virtual machine is 10.0.2.15. I dont know why is not in the same sub-net. I'm new with solaris 11 so I cant tell how to change that. The DHCP is automatic.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you change the IP address of your Solaris, so it much the same subnet.
I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: because I wanted to be done automatically. Maybe I'm missing any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

IP address `10.0.2.15` is normally associated with the Virtualbox NAT network, not the host-only network. If the Solaris guest is using that IP address, then the simplest explanation is that the Solaris guest is still using NAT, rather than the host-only network.

1. Open the VM Virtualbox manager
2. Select the Solaris guest entry, then open its network settings.
3. The adapter should say "Attached to: Host-only network". If it says NAT, change it to "host-only network" and restart the VM.

If the Solaris guest is definitely using the host-only network, then it may be a problem with DHCP in the guest. It may be continuing to use the old NAT address instead of getting an address from DHCP for some reason.

Alternately, maybe the guest has been hardcoded to use the the 10.0.2.15 address, so it's not even trying DHCP.